# onItemClickListener in listview doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to implement a listView using a customized arrayAdapter. I can see my list but, when I try to choose an option of the list, my implemented method onItemClick doesn't work. I've seen similar question here in StackOverflow, but none of the provided solutions work for me... I've tried with `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, with `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` for the elements of each row of my list, and I've also tried making the MainActivity.java to implement onItemClick, but it doesn't work. I know I must have a mistake in my code, but I can't find it...

Here is my code:

guia_general_list.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E6CEC1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstOpciones"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
    android:background="#E6CEC1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item_elements.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutGeneral"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
android:background="@drawable/menu_selector_bar"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivQueVerElement"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOptionName"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivVerOpcion"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/navigation_next_item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ElementsAdapter.java

```
public class ElementsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OptionList>{

int layoutResourceId;
Context context;
OptionList data[] = null;

public ElementsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, OptionList[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    OptionListHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new OptionListHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.ivQueVerElement);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionName);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (OptionListHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    OptionList option = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(option.getOptionName());
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(option.getImageName());

    LinearLayout layoutItem = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.layoutGeneral);


    return row;
}

static class OptionListHolder{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}


public OptionList getItem(int position) {
    return ((OptionList)data[position]);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;

public MainActivity() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.guia_general_list);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    OptionList optionListData[] = new OptionList[]{
            new OptionList("Option1",  R.drawable.image1),
            new OptionList("Option2", R.drawable.image2),
            new OptionList("Option3", R.drawable.image3)
    };

    ElementsAdapter adapter = new ElementsAdapter(this, R.layout.item_elements, optionListData);        

    ListView lstOptions = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstOpciones);

    lstOptions.setAdapter(adapter);

lstOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   "ENTRA!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("xxx","AAA: Position: "+position);

            }

        }
    });


}
```

}

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove the click listener you have set on the linear layout in the adapter. Remove the android:focusable,android:descendantFocusability, and android:clickable elements in XML since they have no bearing on clicks.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. I removed the click listener in the adapter. At first I didn't have it, but I was trying everything... but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, aside from the click listener and the XML elements I pointed out everything looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good except for the item_elements.xml. Views in there are clickable and/or focusable.

These two lines, part of the to  must be removed in order to get your onItemClickekdListener called:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

The other `android:clickable` and `android:focusable` attributes throughout your item_elements.xml are unnecessary, but they should not cause your problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but, don't you need to set `android:clickable` and `android:focusable` as true to be able to click on any element? I removed `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`and now I have my code as I have edited... still doesn't work!!